# How to get total number of tests ran based off of CSV data file?

Tags: automated-testing, java

I inherited two dozen or so java tests and when the suite is ran, everything is printed whether passing or failing. I would like to only print failures/failure logs and get a total count of tests that passed. 
Most of the tests use a data source CSV file and iterate over the rows to verify different data values. IntelliJ prints the total number of tests ran, failures and skips. How can I print the same information so that I can see it when I run the suites via the command line?

When I log anything, it prints every time the test is ran. I only want a final count of the total number of tests that passed printed once.

Below is a sample of the code that runs.

```
public class metaTest
{
    public Iterable getData() throws IOException {
        String inPath = Path.toResource("test.csv");
}
@Test(groups = {"test"}, threadPoolSize = 20)
    @IterateOverReturnValue(method = "getData")
    public void processLine(CsvLine line) throws Exception {

        String URL = line.get(0);   
        AssertMulti asrt = new AssertMulti();
            page_title = page.getTitle();
            asrt.assertNotEmpty(page_title, "Could NOT parse page title");

 try {
            HtmlPage page = HtmlPage.fromUrl(URL);
            response_code = String.valueOf(page.getCode());
} catch (Exception e) {
            asrt.fail(e.getMessage());
            throw e;

        } finally {
            String error_log = asrt.getAsOneString();
            String pass_fail = error_log.isEmpty() ? "PASS" : "FAIL";

            }
}
```

Comment: What build systems are you using. There are many tools in the maven ecosystem that can summarize test results -- look at the surefire documentation.

Comment: TestNG and Maven. I can't find one that logs the summary per test in the terminal. It generates an HTML file after the suite has run, which is fine. I am looking for a way to print the total number of tests when running via the terminal so that I can summarize each of the 24 various files individual tests.

Comment: It generates an XML file for each test class. There is a way to insert a different report writer into the final stages of surefire's reporting to get what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a DotTestListener Class which gets callbacks with test statuses.

In this example from http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng output is printed to the console but you could alter it to store different info and put it in different place.

```
public class DotTestListener extends TestListenerAdapter {
 private int m_count = 0;

    @Override
    public void onTestFailure(ITestResult tr) {
      log("F");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSkipped(ITestResult tr) {
      log("S");
    }

    @Override
    public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult tr) {
       log(".");
    }

    private void log(String string) {
       System.out.print(string);
       if (++m_count % 40 == 0) {
          System.out.println("");
       }
    }
}
```